# From where do I learn Interface Prototyping?

Tags: interface, prototype, arduino, interaction-design

I am interested in prototyping and developing gadgets and devices using arduino board and other stuffs, however I only get tutorials on arduino but not in interface prototyping. I found a book but it is in other language not in English
 (link is :http://prototypinginterfaces.com/)

I also don't know the exact term to look for in Google, for tutorials. That might be the reason why I'm not getting the suitable results. Basically what I want to learn is the same as the book says.

I have no idea from where do I start, and what to look for at first. If anybody can help me, please.

Comment: "Interface Prototyping" is a bit ambiguous term. Are you looking to hook up a Arduino to the USB port of some other computer, and use that computer's OS as the User Interface? (if so, you need to be more specific about which UI platform - native Windows forms, Java, etc.) Or are you trying to add an Ethernet shield and use the Arduino as a web server, and thus looking for info on Arduino hosted HTML web interfaces? The two best sites for learning resources on Arduino Interfaces are http://www.arduino.cc/ and http://www.adafruit.com/tutorials

Comment: Sorry for late response, i don't know the right term but as i have said, those are the things i want to learn

Comment: What i want to learn is exactly the things shown on trailer of the book

Answer (score 2):

from the software perspective, I'd recommend getting into Processing. It's the programming language Arduino is derived from, and with both of them, in tandem, you can code and build interactive prototypes. O'Reilly has some excelent books and video lessons to tackle those:

- [Learning Processing](http://www.learningprocessing.com/) (book and website)
- [Getting started with Processing](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920000570.do)
- [Arduino and Processing in tandem](http://search.oreilly.com/?q=tandem&x=0&y=0), video series

With these two references, most of what the link you provided says, is covered.

From the hardware perspective, you might also enjoy the following:

- Making things Move
- Making thins Talk
- Arduino Cookbook

Sorry for the extreme focus on one editorial house, however, they rock!. Best luck.

Comment: Processing is Java-based, and Arduino is C++ based. Both have the same kind of graphical interface, but this has nothing to do with their respective programming language. However it is true that Processing comes with a library and examples allowing to "easily" interface with Arduino.

Comment: You are right on the technical side regarding what supports each software. I could have been clearer on that; however towards the user and not the machine, what I said remains true. Actually, the Arduino IDE is directly inspired from Processing's IDE, and Arduino as a programming language is based on Wiring, which in turn also builds from Processing ideas. The three of them share a fundamental idea though, and that is to make creating, coding, and physically interacting with the real world, easy and fun for everyone.

Comment: Sorry for late response. What i really want to learn is that, making things move, make tracking system like those shown on trailer of the book. Scan Elements around us via cameras, making your own hardware controller to handle Graphical objects in software, again like the one shown on trailer of the book, in short yes i want to learn exactly what is shown in trailer of the book. Are the above answer you have given me is the right in terms of what i want to learn? Does Arduino and Processing is sufficient some how to know the basics to do what i really want to do?

Comment: Hi monk, yes the links provided by @jdh and the books suggested by me are what you are looking for.